# Standardised measurements imperial and/or metric

Tags: discussion, formatting

Ok, I am in the metric system, many are using the imperial system. I suspect measurements may be used frequently on this site, animal sizes, animal weights, area, volume and weights for feeding.

What is the best protocol when posting measurements? Should users be encouraged to provide metric and imperial measurements or to edit and add both types when viewing posts with one type of measurement, or is just using one specified measurement type ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I´ve asked in metric and got answers in imperial :)

Considering that even [google](https://www.google.com.br/#q=2+in+in+cm) will convert for you as the first answer, in a special box, I´d leave up to the OP to ask as he/she pleases, and the same to the answers.

Comment: Seconded.  The reader can reasonably convert to his preferred units.  Also, we are not the first site to have this problem; Seasoned Advice doesn't have a rule about this and they probably have way more cases of this than we will.

Comment: Like the answerer pointed out, it is relatively easy to convert units. Generally it would be great if one asked in a unit and then got answers using the same units, but it is a relatively easy problem to solve.