# Standardizing units

Tags: discussion, support

There are starting to be more and more posts with numbers in them - often temperature and weight, but the argument can be extended to volume and length. Since Stack Exchange is an international community, can there be measures to standardize the units and measurements on the site, and if so what?

It can get quite confusing for questions that are directly related to a unit of measurement (e.g. temperature), often, the answers have both metric and imperial units (e.g. °F and °C), while some have only one or the other. I'm sure I'm not the only one who's grown up with one unit and can't quite wrap their head around the other.

---

**Related:**

- [Standardised measurements imperial and/or metric](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/standardised-measurements-imperial-and-or-metric)

<sub>*This question is inspired by, and very similar to the question "[Standardized Units?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/standardized-units)" on Seasoned Advice Meta.*</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the author doesn't take it upon themselves to provide conversions, then someone should **edit the post** to improve the answer or question. It's nice to say "standardize it" but it would be even more helpful to **make the post better for everyone**.

So, if you see a post that only includes one type of measurement (e.g. metric) then include an approximate imperial equivalent in parentheses next to the original metric unit though editing.

For example,

> he weighs 10 pounds

should be edited to look like:

> he weighs 10 pounds (4.54 kilograms)

---

<sub>*This answer is inspired by, and very similar to the [answer](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/a/120) on the question "Standardized Units?" on Seasoned Advice Meta.*</sub>

Comment: I'm a lazy person and hate manually converting units. I've been looking vor a handy User Script or similar, but haven't found anything good. I'll report whatever I can dig up.